# How ignore missing fields while reindexing in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have a destination index with only portion of source index, and I only want to reindex these fields from source index to destination index, Can I still using the reindex API or what should I do with this situation? Any solutions or suggestions thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can consider also `excludes` option to exclude undesired fields:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_reindex?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source-index",
    "_source": {
      "excludes": ["exclude_a", "exclude_b"]
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dest-index"
  }
}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

When reindexing, you are able to apply many operations like renaming fields, reindex only docs matching a query or - and that's what you are looking for - reindex only specific fields.

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old_index_name",
    "_source": ["field-a", "field-b", "other_field"]
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "target_index_name"
  }
}
```

Here is the documentation of the feature discussed here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-filter-source

Comment: I have 100 fields. Now I want to consider 99 fields to new index. Should I add all the 99 fields in `_source` or is there any way to ignore the fields?

Comment: You can use a painless script for blacklisting particular fields while reindexing or set your mapping and disable dynamic mapping https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html#dynamic-inner-objects